# Assigning Datepicker to javascript variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I have some very simple js working where a user enters info in a textbox, and the input is repopulated in another area of the document with a click function. Some of the input fields require dates, and I would like them to appear as date pickers. I have tried to set the datepicker as a style in the head of the doc as instructed in this guide http://javarevisited.blogspot.ca/2013/10/how-to-use-multiple-jquery-ui-date.html but it isn't working.

Is this because the variable Id overrides the class ID? Can I assign the datepicker function in the script?

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
  function sayHi(){

  var BPCName = document.getElementById("BPCName");
  var OUTBPC = document.getElementById("OUTBPC");
  var name = BPCName.value;
  OUTBPC.value = " " +name+ ""  


  } // end sayHi


 <style> .datepicker {}</style>


<script>

$(function() {
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();


});

</script>
```

```
<form action = "">



<fieldset>
  <label>Start Date: </label>
  <input type = "text"


  class=datepicker

id = "BPCName" />
```

```
<h1>TEST</h1>
<form action = "">
  <fieldset>
  <label>Start Date: </label>
  <input type = "text"
    class=datepicker
    id = "BPCName" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just need to call Jquery and JqueryUI in your headers then use this

```
$("input.datepicker").datepicker(); 
//this code will set all your inputs with "datepicker" class, to appear the datepicker
//from JqueryUI
```

and you should put

```
class="datepicker"
```

not simply

```
class=datepicker
```

Comment: @Ojay - Please mark the post as the answer to your question.